# Changing class of a div on a checkbox value change

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to change the add a class "isChecked" to the parent div whenever a checkbox is checked. For that I am trying to use ngClass directive.

HTML

```
   <div ng-class="{isChecked: (isChecked_1 == 'true')}">
     <input type="checkbox" id="check_1" ng-model="isChecked_1" />
     <label class="label_1" for="check_1">This is a label</label>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.isChecked{
    background-color: #428bca;
    color: white;
}
```

But this isn't working. Can someone point out my mistake or suggest some better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user checks a checkbox angularJS sets the model to the boolean value `true`. In your code you compare this to the string `'true'` which evaluates to `false`. Thus, you have to compare it to the boolean `true`. This is different from `if` statements where the string `'true'` evaluates to `true`.

Moreover you don't need the manual comparision at all, as it's only purpose is to yield a boolean value. You can change your code to:

```
    <div ng-class="{isChecked: isChecked_1}">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check_1" ng-model="isChecked_1"/>
      <label class="label_1" for="check_1">This is a label</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

By changing the `'true'` to just `true` , it worked.

So the new code is:

```
   <div ng-class="{isChecked: (isChecked_1 == true)}">
     <input type="checkbox" id="check_1" ng-model="isChecked_1" />
     <label class="label_1" for="check_1">This is a label</label>
   </div>
```

Anyone has idea what us is the difference between `variable == 'true'` and `variable == true` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for it. it has methods to add and remove css classes depending upon certain conditions

Comment: Thats not the way to do things. Mixing code is a door to hell. [Spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)